# ros_controllers catkin_make fail

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I'm trying to catkin_make the ros_controllers package on ROS Kinetic but get this error

```
[100%] Built target diff_drive_controller
[100%] Built target vesc_msgs_generate_messages
[100%] Built target diff_drive_generate_messages
[100%] Built target driver_base_generate_messages
In file included from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller.h:75:0,
                 from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/src/joint_trajectory_controller.cpp:34:
/home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/init_joint_trajectory.h: In function ‘Trajectory joint_trajectory_controller::initJointTrajectory(const JointTrajectory&, const ros::Time&, const joint_trajectory_controller::InitJointTrajectoryOptions<Trajectory>&)’:
/home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/init_joint_trajectory.h:336:40: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
       error_string = "Dropping all " + std::to_string(msg.points.size());
                                        ^
/home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/init_joint_trajectory.h:336:40: note: suggested alternatives:

    In file included from /usr/include/boost/exception_ptr.hpp:9:0,
                     from /usr/include/boost/thread/exceptional_ptr.hpp:10,
                     from /usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:23,
                     from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/actionlib/server/action_server.h:41,
                 from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller.h:58,
                 from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/src/joint_trajectory_controller.cpp:34:
/u
sr/include/boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp:492:5: note:   ‘boost::to_string’

         to_string( exception_ptr const & p )
         ^
    In file included from /usr/include/boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp:15:0,
                     from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller.h:43,
                     from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller
    
        /src/joint_trajectory_controller.cpp:34:
    /usr/include/boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp:1167:1: note:   ‘boost::to_string’
     to_string(const dynamic_bitset<Block, Allocator>& b, stringT& s)
     ^
In file included from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller.h:75:0,
                 from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/src/joint_trajectory_controller.cpp:34:
/home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller

    /init_joint_trajectory.h:338:42: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
           error_string += "Last point is " + std::to_string(last_point_dur.toSec());
                                              ^
/home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/init_joint_trajectory.h:338:42: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/exception_ptr.hpp:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/exceptional_ptr.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/actionlib/server/action_server.h:41,
                 from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller

    /joint_trajectory_controller.h:58,
                     from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller
    
    /src/joint_trajectory_controller.cpp:34:
    /usr/include/boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp:492:5: note:   ‘boost::to_string’
         to_string( exception_ptr const & p )
         ^
        In file included from /usr/include/boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp:15:0,
                         from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller.h:43,
                         from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/src/joint_trajectory_controller.cpp:34:
        /usr/include/boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp:1167:1: note:   ‘boost::to_string’
        
     to_string(const dynamic_bitset<Block, Allocator>& b, stringT& s)
     ^
ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/CMakeFiles/joint_trajectory_controller.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/CMakeFiles/joint_trajectory_controller.dir/src/joint_trajectory_controller.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/CMakeFiles/joint_trajectory_controller.dir/src/joint_trajectory_controller.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:14928: recipe for target 'ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/CMakeFiles/joint_trajectory_controller.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/CMakeFiles/joint_trajectory_controller.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Does anyone have any idea on what could be the issue ? I really don't get why it reaches 100%, yet it failed :/
Still pretty new to ROS, sorry if it is a silly question

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309039/ros_controllers-catkin_make-fail/) by [lzheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/37365/lzheng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your issue is simply a C++ issue, the method `to_string` from the library `<string>` is available with C++11. With kinetic, the standard is C++03 (Cf [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#c)), so you have to specify in the `CMakeLists.txt` to use the standard C++11 with this line (just after `project(YOUR_PROJECT)`) :

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lzheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/37365/lzheng/) on 2018-11-21**:
Thank you so much !!! This solved the issue !

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-11-21**:
Glad it worked !